# Change text and html using jquery

Tags: jquery

In HTML I have

```
code exchange org <sup>®</sup>
```

there is space after org I need to delete that space. to make that like this

```
code exchange org<sup>®</sup>
```

The jquery I am using

```
$(div).each(function(){

$(this).text("org <sup>").replace("org<sup>");


});
```

Comment: is `div` a variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/yFA4S/

```
$("div").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("org <sup>", "org<sup>"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('div').each(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(' <sup>','<sup>');
});
```

or

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(' <sup>','<sup>'));
});
```

References

[.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML)

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1):

this should do it: `$(this).text( $(this).text().replace("group <","group<") );`
I hope I was first, anyways hope I helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `replace` method correctly

They this

```
$(div).each(function(){    
   this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace('org <sup>','org<sup>');    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your altered value also like this

```
$(your div here).each(function(){

this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(' <sup>','<sup>');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('div sup').each(function () {
    var prev = this.previousSibling;
    if (prev && prev.nodeType == 3) {
        prev.textContent = $.trim(prev.textContent)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bs92U/)